# conver Datetime String to milliseconds

Tags: android, date, parsing, formatting

I have service that back this json:

```
 JSON={"time":"2015-10-29 14:05:13 +0000"}
```

so I wanna conver it to milliseconds by:

```
String temp = json.getString("time");
            int point = temp.indexOf("+");
            temp = temp.substring(0,point-1);
            SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss");
            Date d = f.parse(temp);
            long milliseconds = d.getTime();
```

and I can see my temp changed to : `2015-10-29 14:05:13` 
but it seems had problem in parsing. what is my formatig problem

Comment: you've put: "yyyy-MMM-dd hh:mm:ss" but you should only have two M's for the month. i.e. "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"

Comment: @user2145222 you was right. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most important improvement is choosing the right pattern with the symbols MM and HH (not hh) and Z:

```
String input = "2015-10-29 14:05:13 +0000";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z");
Date d = sdf.parse(input);
```

- MM is the numerical representation of month consisting of 2 digits while MMM would be an text abbreviation.
- H represents the 24-hour-clock and h the 12-hour-clock.
- Z is the so-called [rfc 822 timezone offset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). You have such an offset in your input so why filtering it out? It is even an error to leave it out because then your formatter interpretes the filtered input in your system timezone (which has probably a different offset than the offset contained in your original input).

Comment: thanks my problem was my mistake to put MMM instead of mm,this format wont work and pars errors. :(

Comment: @Kenji Am not sure if you asked about Z? Anyway, I have added an explanation why you should take into account the parsed offset.

Answer (score 0):

`ss` only returns your data up to seconds. To return milliseconds, you need to use the following:

```
   String temp = json.getString("time");
   int point = temp.indexOf("+");
   temp = temp.substring(0,point-1);
   SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSZZ");
   Date d = f.parse(temp);
   long milliseconds = d.getTime();
```

Hope this helps :)